# Understanding the wording from gprof

Tags: gprof

I wanted to time my program's time to completion, and came across the GNU program GPROF. It seems to be very powerful, but I don't understand some of its output.

I don't understand what this means, could someone please clarify what "sample hit covers x bytes" and "X% of X seconds" means? I don't understand the context of the latter, I understand it is 0.00926 seconds... :

```
    granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) for 0.02% of 46.30 seconds
```

Comment: When somebody says some software is "very powerful", what they mean is "I like it". (Just like when somebody says "studies have shown", what they mean is "I think".) The best way to time something is to put an outer loop around it of, say, 1000 iterations, stopwatch *that*, and divide by 1000.

Comment: I think you're right, I added a time.h type of time_t counter and it gave the correct results of "Cycles: 3.56496e+09, Seconds: 3564.96" (verified by stopwatch), while gprof gave "granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) for 0.00% of 497.96 seconds". The latter either means it only sampled 3 types or it is off by two thirds of the actual time....

Comment: Although I still would like to understand the wording...

Comment: That line is just telling you the sample frequency. i.e. 50 seconds times 0.0002 is 0.01 seconds. When it says "covers 2 bytes" I suspect that means every 2 bytes of machine code has its own counter, so whenever there's an interrupt, it looks at the PC, finds out which 2 bytes of code it's in, and increments that counter, or something that accomplishes the same thing. [*Look here.*](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_chapter/gprof_5.html#SEC12)